# SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer and SQL Server 2008 Express Edition, Replication

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I was looking for some advise on a current task and sifting though on the net I am not finding anything direct. I have full SQL Server 2008 in my central location and then 5 remote sites that use SQL Server 2008 Express for the database services. I am looking for a way to synch or replicate the databases in the 2008 Express instances back to my central 2008 developer edition instance.

What is blocking me is the editions and what is possible, I have been told log shipping and mirroring will not work with Express editions of SQL Server.

One thought was SSIS maybe from the central location pulling from the express instance, but again I don't know if this is possible.

Any ideas however big or small would be really appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot Publish data from a SQL Server Express Edition. Express Edition can only be used as a Subscriber, The cheapest Edition that you will require to be a Publisher will be Standard Edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither log shipping nor mirroring are replication solutions. They are high availability/disaster recovery solutions which allow you to have the **same** database in two (or more with log-sipping) locations. Only the source location can update the database.

What you want is replication, see [Replicating Data to SQL Server Express](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151819%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Merge Replication will allow you to update data at the periphery (on the SQL Express instances).

Note that all scenarios require *static and available* SQL Express instances. Replication will not work with if the SQL express instances are mobile (show up on the network with different names/IPs, think a laptop being moved around) or occasionally available (again, think a laptop that appears on and off the network as the user opens it in the corp WiFi or at home). For mobile/occasionally connected scenarios the right approach is [Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/).

> One thought was SSIS maybe from the central location pulling from the express instance, but again I don't know if this is possible.

No, is not possible in practice, because of the impossibility of detecting changes ('what records need to be pulled?') and the lack of support for update conflict resolution.

Another approach, which I did see it deployed with success, is to use [Service Broker](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893.aspx) since is freely available in Express. But it only solves the problem of transport (delivery the changes), and does not address detecting changes (usually solved via either app specific logic or via triggers) and applying the changes (this is not hard to solve though). Update conflicts are hard to handle.

Comment: Thats brilliant thanks, The replication can be 12 hours out so my SSIS idea was just the whole DB each night maybe

Comment: If it takes 12 hours now, will take 16 hours in a year, and will take 36 hours when something goes bad (network slow, human error, etc). Is really not feasible.

Comment: BTW your central hub cannot be a Developer Edition, as a Developer Edition is not licensed for production use. A Standard Edition will work.